# What is causing TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using this code for domain checker. However I get an error saying bytes not callable. Can someone please explain me how to solve this.

```
def make_whois_query(domain):

   #Execute whois and parse the data to extract specific data    
  #debug("Sending a WHOIS query for the domain %s" % domain)

try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['whois', domain],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except Exception as e:
    print("Unable to Popen() the whois binary. Exception %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    whois_data = p.communicate()[0]
except Exception as e:
    print("Unable to read from the Popen pipe. Exception %s" % e)
    sys.exit(1)


return(parse_whois_data(whois_data))


def parse_whois_data(whois_data):

   #Grab the registrar and expiration date from the WHOIS data

debug("Parsing the whois data blob %s" % whois_data)
expiration_date = "00/00/00 00:00:00"
registrar = "Unknown"

for line in whois_data.splitlines():
line 103        if any(expire_string in line for expire_string in EXPIRE_STRINGS):
        expiration_date = dateutil.parser.parse(line.partition(": ")[2], ignoretz=True)

    if any(registrar_string in line for registrar_string in
           REGISTRAR_STRINGS):
        registrar = line.split("Registrar:")[1].strip()

return expiration_date, registrar
```

I get the error saying `line 92`, in `make_whois_query`

> return(parse_whois_data(whois_data))    line 103, in parse_whois_data
>       for line in whois_data(): TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: Please edit your code, the format is too messy

Comment: The error message talks about `whois_data():`, but this part isn't present in the code...

Comment: whois_data here is defined as  whois_data = p.communicate()[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```
whois_data = p.communicate()[0]
```

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.

So in your case `whois_data` is `bytes` object, not `str` as expected, so code `for line in whois_data():` (note, exception doesn't correspond to your provided code) fails. To fix this you should convert `whois_data` to `str`
or open open stdout in text mode.

Comment: yes indeed! but why does it say TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: `whois_data()` - you tried to apply `()` operation to `bytes` object

Comment: you need to decode the bytes using utf-8 or whatever encoding is used, so `whois_data.decode("utf-8")`